# Emergency mode due to filesystem check

Tags: boot, filesystem, maintenance

On bootup, filesystem check occurs and it stops at 61% and I am redirected to a page with the message you are in the emergency mode. I don't know what to do next.

This is the message that I get at the screen

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type ....... 
Press Enter for maintenance
(Or press ctrl+D to continue):
```

But when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> it again directs me back to the same screen.

Comment: status please...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I safely fsck my root partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090066/how-can-i-safely-fsck-my-root-partition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a manual `fsck`...

For 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Since you have a separate /home, do the following...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type the following commands...

  - sudo fsck -f /dev/sda4
  - sudo fsck -f /dev/sda8

Comment: Hey @heynnema, i tried your solution for ubuntu18.04. it still shows the same error.

Comment: @ujjwalgupta From above... at the emergency screen, hit the ENTER key to get to the root prompt... not control-d. Then do the command that they illustrate there. Then, enter these commands... `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`, take good pictures with your smart phone and upload them to imgur.com, and give me the URL.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I could not run the commands mentioned in the emergency screen as the packages that the commands refer to are not installed. Here are the links to the outputs of the commands that you suggested.

    https://imgur.com/ZZi3IDB
    https://imgur.com/rDb4Jtk

Comment: @ujjwalgupta Thanks, that was helpful. Please do Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: That worked for me. Although it changed my root password I fixed it using the recovery mode. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your system. From the grub menu, choose the Recovery mode option. From there do a manual fsck.
 `fsck /dev/[root directory]`. 
For example, if your root directory is sda1 , your command should look like :
   `fsck /dev/sda1`
If a prompt appears, just press 'y'.
Once it completes, resume the normal boot.

Comment: This won't work. The `fsck` in the recovery menu doesn't work. On systems >=18.04 you can no longer fsck from the root prompt.